# Prove Piecewise Function Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-2, & \text{if }x < 0 \\
1, & \text{if }x > 0\\
0, & \text{if }x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Hey guys I need some help showing that this function is integrable on the closed interval $[-1,2]$.

So far my idea has been to show $$U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

The only problem is the point $(0,0)$ on the function.

I don't understand how to handle that.

Can I just say that $U(f,P)$ for some partition will equal to $3$ and then find a partition $P$ for which $$3-L(f,P)<\epsilon?$$

Comment: If you make the interval(s) containing 0 sufficiently narrow, you can make the difference between upper an lower sums as small as you want, namely at most $|1-(-2)|=3$ times this interval width.

Comment: Hint: look at partitions like $\{[-1,-\epsilon],[-\epsilon,\epsilon],[\epsilon,2]\}$ for smaller and smaller (positive) $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a partition of $[-1,2]$. Taking Arthur's hint, have the partition be of the form,
$$[-1,-\delta],[-\delta,\delta],[\delta,2]$$ for appropriately small $\delta >0$.

The supremum of $f(x)$ is -2 on the first subinterval, $1$ on the second subinterval, and $1$ on the third subinterval (verify it!). Thus the upper sum is given by
$$U_{f,\sigma}=(1-\delta)\cdot -2 + 2\delta \cdot 1 + (2-\delta)\cdot 1=3\delta$$
The infimum of $f$ on the first interval is $-2$, as well as $-2$ on the second subinterval, and $1$ on the last (verify). Thus the lowers sum is given by
$$L_{f,\sigma}=(1-\delta)(-2)+2\delta \cdot (-2) +(2-\delta)\cdot 1=-3\delta$$
Thus, $U_{f,\sigma}-L_{f,\sigma}=6\delta$ and it should be clear how small to make $\delta$.

Comment: So after you get 2$\delta$ we need a $\delta$ < $\epsilon$ /2.  We could choose $\epsilon$ /3 and get Uf-Lf=$\epsilon$ - $\epsilon$ /3 which finishes the proof of 2/3 $\epsilon$ < $\epsilon$.  Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Just one question though.  Why isn't the infimum on the interval [-$\delta$,$\delta$] set as -2?

Comment: Because i messed up haha. This will affect the bound

Comment: @jeff I have edited my answer with this fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $x$ at which $f$ is discontinuous, $x$ can be contained in an interval as small as you please. Make sure to include this small interval in your partition.